# Classes in package freemarker.template.utility available in template?

Tags: freemarker

I see there are a number of classes available in the package freemarker.template.utility. Is there a way for these to be exposed in the data model so that they can be used inside a template?

It seems like that might be what they are for but I can't figure out how to access them from my templates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of the desired object, and drop it into the data-model like anything else. Or, you can set said objects as `Configuration`-level "shared variables", via `Configuration.setSharedVariable`.

Comment: I thought of that.  But take the freemarker.template.utility.DateUtil class for example. There's no visible constructor for it, and it contains only static items. It's not clear to me how I can create an object of this class.

Comment: You can add something like this to the data-model or to the shared variables: `((BeansWrapper) configuration.getObjectWrapper()).getStaticModels().get("com.example.MyStaticUtilityClass")`. However, `DateUtil` was never meant to be used from templates. It's pretty much only exists because FreeMarker needs those utilities internally.